# I'm looking to free up space in a table with pictures

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a SQL Server instance I manage with a 1TB hard drive and 100GB free. Because of the RAID setup, they are quite pricey for our small business to add more hard drive space. Also we are getting rid of the server in the near future, so don't want to invest anymore in it. That being said, the software application we use stores bunches of images in the database, and the database side is growing at a rate of 30GB a month, so in 3 months, I expect us to be at near capacity. The thing is, we have 7 years of pictures in this database and only need 1-2 years. I expect to delete 5 years worth of pictures to free up space. However, my understanding is with AutoGrowth and the way SQL Server allocates disk space, just simply deleting the records may not free up space like I would expect without doing a shrink (and I know all the bad things that go along with that, indexing, performance, etc.). So my question is, how do I get rid of these old pictures stored in a single table and reclaim that space, to buy us enough time for the next 6 months - 1 year until we deactivate this server anyways?

I haven't deleted anything just yet....

Comment: Even if you `DELETE` the *rows* in the database this won't free up (physical) space; database files don't get smaller when you delete data in their database. Instead what happens is the database file itself has "free space" so that when more space is needed that "free" space is used instead and the database file doesn't grow. Though you can, it is generally suggested you *don't* shrink your databases as this can result in fragmentation, which can be a much bigger problem.

Comment: I was wondering about that. So if I delete the rows, it will essentially stop the bleeding and it will not grow until that allocated space is filled up? So if I delete 75% of the table, it should take a very long time for the disk space to change, at least on that one table?

Comment: Your looking at a situation where Autogrowth has run amuck and you're mopped into the proverbial corner.   IF you resort to shrinking -  Which it really looks like your only option here sadly with you limited resources, [This Solution](https://gist.github.com/tcartwright/ea60e0a38fac25c847e39bced10ecd04) might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: @Zak I don't necessarily need to reclaim the space if I can just stop the bleeding.

Comment: Well -- Think of it this way then .. If you `DELETE` 2 years worth of images ..  The database won't shrink ..  But you'll have 100GB free for longer than a year.  Physical disk space will stay the same, as the database fills back up ...

Comment: @zak I was hoping that's how it works, thanks!